# Why does Keras not generalize my data?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Ive been trying to implement a basic multilayered LSTM regression network to find correlations between cryptocurrency prices.

After running into unusable training results, i've decided to play around with some sandbox code, to make sure i've got the idea right before trying again on my full dataset.

**The problem** is I can't get Keras to generalize my data.

```
ts = 3
in_dim = 1

data = [i*100 for i in range(10)]

# tried this, didn't accomplish anything 
# data = [(d - np.mean(data))/np.std(data) for d in data]

x = data[:len(data) - 4]
y = data[3:len(data) - 1]

assert(len(x) == len(y))

x = [[_x] for _x in x]
y = [[_y] for _y in y]

x = [x[idx:idx + ts] for idx in range(0, len(x), ts)]
y = [y[idx:idx + ts] for idx in range(0, len(y), ts)]

x = np.asarray(x)
y = np.asarray(y)
```

x looks like this:

```
[[[  0]
  [100]
  [200]]

 [[300]
  [400]
  [500]]]
```

and y:

```
[[[300]
  [400]
  [500]]

 [[600]
  [700]
  [800]]]
```

and this works well when I predict using a *very* similar dataset, but doesn't generalize when I try a similar sequence with scaled values

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(BatchNormalization(
    axis = 1,
    input_shape = (ts, in_dim)))

model.add(LSTM(
    100,
    input_shape = (ts, in_dim),
    return_sequences = True))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(in_dim)))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = 'rmsprop')

model.fit(x, y, epochs = 2000, verbose = 0)

p = np.asarray([[[10],[20],[30]]])
prediction = model.predict(p)
print(prediction)
```

prints

```
[[[ 165.78544617]
  [ 209.34489441]
  [ 216.02174377]]]
```

I want

```
[[[ 40.0000]
  [ 50.0000]
  [ 60.0000]]]
```

how can I format this so that when i plug in a sequence with values that are of a completely different scale, the network will still output its predicted value? I've tried normalizing my training data, but the results are still entirely unusable.

What have I done wrong here?

Comment: I also found this discussion of the use of LSTM for autoregression on univariate data useful: https://machinelearningmastery.com/suitability-long-short-term-memory-networks-time-series-forecasting/ - can't say it fully answered my questions, but it offers some insight into how sometimes LSTMs fail to live up to expectations on time series forecasting.

Comment: You're overestimating the power of deep learning. You only give it multiplies of 100 as input and expect it to generalize to multiples of 10 as well. Because 10 is no special number, this transfer learning should also apply to multiples of any number in general. But how should your model know that this is the task it is supposed to do? Your training data tells that in no way. The task could also be to simply add 100 to the input at the current time step. In order to be able to generalize, you need to give the model training data that contains examples of generalization.

Answer (score 0):

How about transform your input data before sending into your LSTM, use something like sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler? after prediction you can call scaler.inverse_transform(prediction)